# How is the feasibility checked in this step of Rosen's gradient method?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, linear-algebra

I know that feasibility can be checked by checking the value of the new objective function with the previous one and by taking the gradient ans direction. But I cannot understand what is used to find the value of α<sub>1</sub> = 1/4 here. I'm fairly new to this topic and can't seem to understand most of the topic due to this.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the first constraint: it requires that `x1 - 2 x2 <= 0`.

Now, within that `Max` we are looking at all possible values of `alpha` that are greater than zero, and we want the largest `alpha` value such that

```
1 + 4 alpha
    1
```

"is feasible", ie satisfies all constraints. In particular, in order to satisfy that first constraint, we must have

```
x1 <= 2 x2
```

which here is

```
1 + 4 alpha <= 2
    4 alpha <= 1
      alpha <= 1/4
```

It is clear then that the `Max` `alpha` that satisfies the first constraint is 1/4. We can check that with this `alpha` the other constraints are also satisfied; and we're done.